# Closure Tree gem: NoMethodError: undefined method `[]=' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm working with the closure_tree gem.  My model hierarchy is based around an "Org" (organization) with an integer parent_id.

I have setup all organizations to a parent_id (pointing to an existant ID), except the root node, which has a null parent_id.

When I call Org.hash_tree, I get:

```
Org Load (1.1ms)  SELECT `orgs`.* FROM `orgs` INNER JOIN (
SELECT descendant_id, MAX(generations) as depth
FROM `org_hierarchies`
GROUP BY descendant_id

) AS generation_depth
ON `orgs`.id = generation_depth.descendant_id  ORDER BY generation_depth.depth

NoMethodError: undefined method `[]=' for nil:NilClass

from /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.1.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/closure_tree-5.1.1/lib/closure_tree/hash_tree.rb:52:in `block in build_hash_tree'
```

Any ideas of the cause of this issue or tips on where to look?

A simple recursive function that calls the children method on each org, starting at the root works as expected, returns a tree of organizations.

Answer (score 1):

Org.rebuild! solved this for me. The hierarchies table was corrupted somehow.